# BroadcastReceiver: Create instance and override inline?

Tags: java, android

I don't fully understand how you can create an instance of BroadcastReceiver and then override inline. I am using to creating a class and "extending" another class and then overriding in the subclass.

I am coming from .NET so that's probably why it is a little strange; would anyone help me understand it, as I really don't understand what is going on?

Here is what I am talking about

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver dynamicReceiver 
            = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // TODO

       }
    };
```

As you can see above it is created as a instance within a class and then overriding its methods.

Comment: What is the question? Because snipped you showed up is correct.

Comment: As stated I don't understand what is going on, how is it possible to create an instance of class inline and then override its methods. Normally this is done using classes and extend and then you override in the subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java allows you to create anonymous classes. These classes are created via

```
'new' <type> '(' <constructor-args> ')' '{' <class-body> '}'
```

expression. Such class is actually compiled into separate class file named 'parent-type'$'ord'.class. This type is then instantiated as normal and instance is returned as a result of the expression.

These anonymous classes share features with inner classes, ie, you can access fields of outer class directly or via OuterClass.this syntax. They also however can also access final variables in current scope.

See more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.